# Get JSON URL From String in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, json, nsdictionary, nsjsonserialization

I just try to deploy client server apps in Objective-C. I get an json string like this from server when I make a query:

```
@"{"url":"http://my-company.com/json"}".
```

How do I extract `the http://my-company.com/json` directly using Objective C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read more about [NSJSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/foundation/reference/nsjsonserialization_class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
NSString *jsonString = @"{\"url\":\"http://my-company.com/json\"}";
NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSError *e;
NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&e];
NSString *url = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"url"];
NSLog(@"url: %@", url);
```

Comment: Only one issue:  You should check if jsonDict is nil, and, if so, log `e` and take an error path.

Comment: @HotLicks: Yes, i already do the checking because if its nil it will crash.Thanks...